# Compute a series with a Fourier series

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, fourier-analysis

I got the following function:
$f(x)=( \frac{x}{ \pi })^{2}$
With the fourier series:
$\widetilde{f(x)} =  \frac{1}{3} + \ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n}\frac{4}{ n^{2}  \pi ^{2}} cos(nx)$

Now I must compute the series:
$\ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{ n^{4}}$

Any ideas?

Comment: I‘m sorry I missed some parts of the series, now it should be correct

Comment: Use Parseval's Theorem: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ParsevalsTheorem.html

Comment: Thanks bro, I totally forgot about that Theorem